# How to make three.js run in React Native (without WebView)?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-native

I am looking for solution to integrate React Native with three.js. From what I've know, three.js runs in DOM. Is there any way to use three.js in without render to DOM? I use three.js for render 3D object. The example can be looked at https://github.com/tweedegolf/minecraft-character-configurator, and need solutions to port into React Native.
Thanks :)

Comment: Remember someone was talking about an experiment to do just this in the toxicfork/react-three-renderer Gitter channel, don't know what became of the project, sorry I don't have more info but it's a start!

Comment: I wonder about performance and guess you'd get much better out of true native OpenGL API, which should run _alongside_ RNative just fine.

Comment: Thanks @WylieКулик for the suggestion. I'm curious how to convert any model I've create from Cinema4D/3dsmax/Blender into OpenGL code. Do you have any idea? :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with high level frameworks in OpenGL, sorry.  I would imagine it's doable and automatable to some extent with custom translation scripting, but that's just a guess and I also guess it would be a chore.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at Expo's GLView component, as well as expo-three, their Three.js integration. It is pretty buggy at the moment but you might get results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have see some examples, and it seems it doesn't support load 3D model from file (Cinema4D/3dsmax/Blender).

Comment: Indeed, it seems it requires to load the obj file as an Expo asset and then to import it. I'm having the same problem at the moment, but I'm talking with the expo-three maintainer on their forum, they're pretty responsive : https://forums.expo.io/t/missing-gl-interfaces-make-glview-fail/1723/7